# Returning dataset from tf.data.Dataset.map() causes 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'get_shape' error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the Dataset API to create an input pipeline.  I'm using the tf.data.Dataset.map() method in a pattern similar to the following:

```
def mapped_fn(_):
    X = tf.random_uniform([3,3])
    y = tf.random_uniform([3,1])
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,y))
    return dataset

with tf.Session() as sess:
    first = tf.random_uniform([1,2])         
    unimportant_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(first)
    dataset = unimportant_dataset.map(mapped_fn)
    sess.run(dataset)
```

I'm getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`

The overall context is that `mapped_fn` deserializes an Example protobuf (represented by `unimportant_dataset` in this case) from a .tfrecords file, reshapes the feature vector (`X`), and needs to return a dataset with elements defined by slices from the new feature vector (of shape `(3,)` in this case).  I've gotten a similar error when returning a `ZipDataset`.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[DomJack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50811745/3574081) is absolutely correct about the signature of [`Dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map): it expects the return value of the passed `mapped_fn` to be one or more tensors (or sparse tensors).

If you do have a function that returns a `Dataset`, you can use `Dataset.flat_map()` to flatten and concatenate all of the returned datasets into a single dataset, as follows:

```
def mapped_fn(_):
    X = tf.random_uniform([3,3])
    y = tf.random_uniform([3,1])
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,y))
    return dataset

# Generate 100 dummy elements.
unimportant_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)

# Convert each dummy element into a dataset of 3 nested elements, and concatenate them.
dataset = unimportant_dataset.flat_map(mapped_fn)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map_fn` passed to `tf.data.Dataset.map` should take the tensors of a single example from the calling dataset and return the tensors of the returned dataset.

e.g.

```
def map_fn(example_proto):
  features, labels = parse_example_proto(example_proto)
  # do data augmentation here
  return features, labels

dataset = tf.data.TfRecordsDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle().map(
  map_fn, num_parallel_calls=8).prefetch(1)
features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map), it looks like the `map()` function should return a `Dataset`.  Is there some conversion under the hood that I'm overlooking?

Comment: The map function returns a dataset, but the first argument to map is itself a function, and that function should return tensors.